# MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy hanging before first epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to run a simple MNIST neural net on multiple cluster nodes (3 nodes with 1 GPU each), but it keeps stopping before the first epoch prints. I'm able to get all the nodes to sync, but right before it starts (maybe in the model.fit function) it just stops and doesn't do anything.

Any help is appreciated!

My TF_CONFIG looks like this:
`TF_CONFIG='{"cluster": {"worker": ["ip1:88888", "ip2:88888",  "ip3:88888"]}, "task": {"index": 0, 1, or 2, "type": "worker"}}' python fileName.py`

And my code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import time

def get_compiled_model():
    # Make a simple 2-layer densely-connected neural network.
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,))
    x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(10)(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
    )
    return model


def get_dataset():
    batch_size = 32
    num_val_samples = 10000

    # Return the MNIST dataset in the form of a `tf.data.Dataset`.
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    # Preprocess the data (these are Numpy arrays)
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 784).astype("float32") / 255
    x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 784).astype("float32") / 255
    y_train = y_train.astype("float32")
    y_test = y_test.astype("float32")

    # Reserve num_val_samples samples for validation
    x_val = x_train[-num_val_samples:]
    y_val = y_train[-num_val_samples:]
    x_train = x_train[:-num_val_samples]
    y_train = y_train[:-num_val_samples]
    return (
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(batch_size),
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val)).batch(batch_size),
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test)).batch(batch_size),
    )


# Create a MirroredStrategy.
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
print("Number of devices: {}".format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

# Open a strategy scope.
with strategy.scope():
    # Everything that creates variables should be under the strategy scope.
    # In general this is only model construction & `compile()`.
    model = get_compiled_model()

# Train the model on all available devices.
train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = get_dataset()
start = time.time()
print("Fit")
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_data=val_dataset, steps_per_epoch=25)
end = time.time()
print("Time:", end - start)
# Test the model on all available devices.
model.evaluate(test_dataset)
```